# dynamically populate options and trigger jquery chosen

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use jquery chosen plugin for one of the requirement. Here are the steps.

1. select tag where chosen is  applied is sitting in 'div' which is hidden( div will be shown on click of a button).
2. options tag in 'select' will be populated dynamically.

steps taken to trigger chosen.

```
            $(function()
            {
              $("select").chosen();
            }
```

=====
this is what i am doing to update the  and triggering the chosen again.

```
            for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              $("select").append("<option value='value"+i+"'>Value"+i+"</option>");
            }

            $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

After doing all these, i am not getting the proper UI or Chosen is not getting triggered.
Can any one take a look ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your complete code or create jsfiddle with your source, below I added one solution with fiddle to get an idea

Answer (score 5):

See this fiddle for dependent lists dynamic behavior with choosen plug-in

http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/ep37owwr/

**HTML:**

```
Parent List:
<select id="countryList" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." style="width:350px;" multiple="" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
    <option value="c1">Country-1</option>
    <option value="c2">Country-2</option>
    <option value="c3">Country-3</option>
    <option value="c4">Country-4</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
Dependent List:
<select id="stateList" data-placeholder="State...by selected counry" style="width:350px;" multiple="" tabindex="2"></select>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#countryList,#stateList").chosen();
    $("#countryList").on('change', function (e) {
        var data = {
            c1: [{ Value: "c1s1", Text: "C1-State1" }, { Value: "c1s2", Text: "C1-State2" }],
            c2: [{ Value: "c2s1", Text: "C2-State1" }],
            c3: [{ Value: "c3s1", Text: "C3-State1" }, { Value: "c3s2", Text: "C3-State2" }],
            c4: [{ Value: "c4s1", Text: "C4-State1" }]
        };

        updateStates(data);
    });
});

function updateStates(data) {
    var $SubItems = [],
        values = $("#countryList").val();
    if (values) $.each(values, function (i, c) {
        $.each(data[c], function (index, item) {
            $SubItems.push($("<option/>", { value: item.Value, text: item.Text }));
        });
    });

    $("#stateList").empty().append($SubItems).trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton Venkata, your statement $("#stateList").empty().append($SubItems).trigger("chosen:updated"); worked for me ..

Comment: I'm glad that helps, Please mark as answer so that this case would be useful for others

Comment: Same, this worked for me.  I marked this as correct.  Great work! $("#stateList").empty().append($SubItems).trigger("chosen:updated");